# Web Based Map application development

Tags: dictionary, webserver

I am trying to develop a web based map application where the user can interact with the map. But I am new to this field and do not have much idea about how to approach this. Basically I want to use a static map created by me, so I think google map API s may not be used in this case. My development platform is unix. Can you please suggest what language I should use to write the server and also what kind of free tools can be used to implement the map part?
Thanx...

Comment: Hey can you tell me how you achieved this, using your own map for rendering it on a website

Comment: Tell us what you *do* know. Do we have to tell you to first learn Javascript? Or first learn what HTML is? I use www.openlayers.org for all my web mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading up on the Google Maps API 3. You can add overlays or even add your own tiles using the API. Specifically, I suggest looking into the GroundLayers section of the V3 API here [GroundOverlays](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#GroundOverlays)